# Sorting binary matrix columns based on most significant bit in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

So I have a 2D array that looks like: `[[0, 1, 1][1, 0, 0][0,0,1]]` where all the values are stored as ints but they represent the actual bit. The values in the first row are considered the most significant. Assuming each column is some integer based on the bits in the column, I would like to sort the columns in decreasing order, so that it looks like `[[1,1,0][0,0,1][0,0,1]]`. However, I'm very lost on how to achieve this in python. It was suggested that I use radix sort, but I'm lost on how this helps me in my case. I've written the two matrices below so it's easier to visualize.

`011   110
 100   001
 001   100`

My approach: read each column, convert to int, sort the ints, map back to column. But this approach can be very convoluted if I'm wokring with matrices with dimensions `1000x10000`

But I feel as though there should be a more clever way to do this, especially in python. How should I approach this?

Comment: I don't understand the logic going from `[[0, 1, 1][1, 0, 0][0,0,1]]` to `[[1,1,0][0,0,1][0,0,1]]`

Comment: transpose it, and you'll know.

Comment: Consider each column as bits that comprise an int. Then `101` is 5, `100` is 4, and `010` is 2. So I put the column representing 5 in the beginning, 4 next, and then 2. Does that clarify?

Comment: Ah yes, then that's just your answer: transpose, sort, transpose back.

Comment: Even if I transpose, I want to sort the entire row. So does that mean, I consider every row as an int?

Comment: No. The lists will be sorted by the same fashion without any int conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said transpose, sort, transpose back:

```
a = [[0, 1, 1],[1, 0, 0],[0,0,1]]
a = list(zip(*a))
a.sort(reverse=True)
a = list(map(list,zip(*a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
b = list(map(list, zip(*a)))
c = sorted(b, reverse=True)
d = list(map(list, zip(*c)))
```

Comment: You don't really have to do the conversion. Once you transpose them, you get them as binary strings, just in a form of a list. Then, just sort.

Comment: What's your problem with this (and my answer) @MohanavelT? It does exactly the job in a more clever way than the int conversion. Precisely what OP wants as far as I can tell. And your definition of spam is strange...